# Privileges and badges links on Area 51 refer to the FAQ page

Tags: bug, area-51, hyperlinks, top-bar

Links from the achievements popup (privileges and badges) on the top bar refer to the FAQ page on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/):

> [image: FAQ]

This is probably a stub for privileges, but the badges page exists on Area 51 (see the proper link on the right side of the screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

The links for privileges and badges from top bar refers to `https://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges` and `https://area51.stackexchange.com/help/badges` respectively. But as we know Area51 doesn't have `/help` pages and that's why those links redirected to `/faq`.

It can be fixed to refer correct destination (eliminating `/help`):

- https://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges
- https://area51.stackexchange.com/badges

Now, talking about Area51 Meta, surprisingly it has a (`/help`) `https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges` candidate for badges and even if you tries https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/badges (eliminating `/help`), it redirects to the working `https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges`

But for privileges, it inconsistently suffers the same bug as that of Area51.